# How to design a immutable append-only database?

Tags: sql, database, database-design

for a project I need to implement a database which is **immutable** and only allows new entries. **Editing or deleting entries should be impossible in any case.**

I was thinking about a database which allows editing and deleting only for admins (so only me). However, I'm unsure if that is 100% safe or if it's possible to illegally get admin rights and forge the data. So the best solution would be to have a database which does not offer editing or deleting in the first place.

Suggestions appreciated! Thanks

Comment: You can always use triggers to prevent changes. If you implement pre-update and pre-delete triggers for each table that **always raise exceptions**, then only inserts and selects will be possible. A lot of work, if you have many tables, though, but possible.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. On the application side it would be an idea, but what do I do if something snoops the database file and runs SQL injections outside the application? @TheImpaler

Answer (score 3):

PostgreSQL supports, since 9.5, [Row Security Policies](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-rowsecurity.html), which allow you to define select, insert, delete and update policies depending on the user, and/or some fields values in the table. You might find what you search there.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to GRANT separated rights to `INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE` to users but it may be insufficient for some business rules. However, many DBMS (SQL Server for example) support [INSTEAD OF triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql) which can quietly bypass any `DELETE/UPDATE` and process `INSERT` depending on your custom criteria implemented in trigger code.

You can also define an updateable view having INSTEAD OF triggers to insert-only data.